# Self signed certificate with iOS in LAN

Tags: ios, self-signed, zeroconf, local-network

my first question here :)

SITUATION:

- I have iOS app connected in local network to my raspberry server.
- Local network is NOT connected to internet.
- I use zeroconf/bonjour to find server (I dont know its ip in advance)

Is there some possibility to communicate iOS app with server using https self-signed certificate?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like ios dont allows https requests (I am using axios) to server with self-signed certificate. It works in postman - get/post requests, but ios do nothing. I found some solution in case that you send key to email and user download it to phone and set "thrust this". But I cant do this to user...